# Create a drawable canvas inside an XML layout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I am new to Java and android, so I don't know if it's possible, but I would like to create a dynamically drawable surface/view/place in my app. I know how to replace my whole XML layout with a drawable canvas, but that's not what I want. I would prefer this drawable surface to be on top of (or in) my static layout and I still haven't found out how to do that. Below an illustration of what I mean:

[image: example app]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: why dont you use relativelayout ? In which First Layout will be your required layout and second will be the View which dynamically add the view on canvas. This way you can able to see the Canvas above all the layout which you have define. Hope you got my point.

Answer (score 1):

You have different options. You can put a custom `View` and override its `onDraw()` method to draw with its `Canvas`. Another option is to use `SurfaceView` (which provides a `Thread` for drawing with its `Canvas`, more efficient for more complex drawing). Here is more details about for the [first option](http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/custom-drawing.html) and [second option](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView.html).

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. I would like to go with your 2nd option, but how does it 'provides a thread with it's canvas'?

Comment: I think this is too complicated for what I want this surface to do: just draw some lines on it to learn how to use it. I think your first option is better for doing this simple task. Thanks for the suggestions anyway.